# How to do a password validation animation in Flutter

Tags: flutter, validation, dart, passwords

I'm trying to make a function that gets the value from the password `TextFormField()` and checks for if the user has an upperCase, lowerCase, number and special characters in it and according to that it will update the `Text('Must have an upperCase letter')` widgets that I have and change their colour and icon accordingly.

With the code I have I keep getting this error:

```
setState() or markNeedsBuild called during build
```

A working example of what I'm trying to do is [here](https://www.flipsnack.com/accounts/sign-up.html)

[image: An example of what I'm trying to do]

My function so far (which is my validator as well):

```
String isPasswordCompliant(String password, [int minLength = 6]) {
      if (password.length < minLength || password.isEmpty) {
        return 'Password must be at least 6 characters long';
      }
      if (password.contains(RegExp(r"[a-z]"))) {
        setState(() {
          _passwordChecker.hasLowercase = true;
        });
      }
      if (password.contains(RegExp(r"[A-Z]"))) {
        setState(() {
          _passwordChecker.hasUppercase = true;
        });
      }
      if (password.contains(RegExp(r"[0-9]"))) {
        setState(() {
          _passwordChecker.hasDigits = true;
        });
      }
      if (password.contains(RegExp(r'[!@#$%^&*(),.?":{}|<>]'))) {
        setState(() {
          _passwordChecker.hasSpecialCharacters = true;
        });
      } else {
        return null;
      }
  }
```

How I'm implementing the function:

```
                    TextFormField(
                      decoration: const InputDecoration(labelText: 'Password'),
                      obscureText: true,
                      controller: _passwordController,
                      textInputAction: TextInputAction.next,
                      onFieldSubmitted: (_) {
                        FocusScope.of(context)
                            .requestFocus(_confirmPasswordFocusNode);
                      },
                      focusNode: _passwordFocusNode,
                      validator: (value) => isPasswordCompliant(value),
                      onSaved: (value) {
                        _authData['password'] = value;
                      },
                    ),
```

My Text() widgets:

```
class PasswordChecker extends StatelessWidget {
  PasswordChecker(this._passwordChecker);
  final PasswordValidationModel _passwordChecker;
  // final _passwordChecker = PasswordValidationModel();
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
      children: [
        TextButton.icon(
          icon: _passwordChecker.hasUppercase == true
              ? Icon(Icons.done)
              : Icon(Icons.clear),
          label: Text(
            'Must have at least one upperCase letter',
          ),
          onPressed: () {},
        ),
        TextButton.icon(
          icon: _passwordChecker.hasLowercase == true
              ? Icon(Icons.done)
              : Icon(Icons.clear),
          label: Text(
            'Must have at least one lowerCase letter',
          ),
          onPressed: () {},
        ),
        TextButton.icon(
          icon: _passwordChecker.hasDigits == true
              ? Icon(Icons.done)
              : Icon(Icons.clear),
          label: Text(
            'Must have at least one number',
          ),
          onPressed: () {},
        ),
        TextButton.icon(
          icon: _passwordChecker.hasSpecialCharacters == true
              ? Icon(Icons.done)
              : Icon(Icons.clear),
          label: Text(
            'Must have at least one special character',
          ),
          onPressed: () {},
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Have you considered using Regex? [this](https://www.section.io/engineering-education/password-strength-checker-javascript/) might help!

Comment: @AbdelbakiBoukerche I am using RegExp but I'm dividing it so that i can check separately for the values in order to update the Text() widgets independently.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After I did some more research I found a similar [project](https://medium.com/flutter-community/flutter-password-validation-animation-79ab2bceb600) and came up with a simple solution, by adding a `addListener()` to the password controller and initializing it in `initState()` and doing the logic there.

```
@override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _passwordController.addListener(() {
      setState(() {
        if (_passwordChecker.hasLowercase =
            _passwordController.text.contains(RegExp(r'[a-z]'))) {
          _passwordChecker.hasLowercase = true;
        }
        if (_passwordChecker.hasUppercase =
            _passwordController.text.contains(RegExp(r'[A-Z]'))) {
          _passwordChecker.hasUppercase = true;
        }
        if (_passwordChecker.hasDigits =
            _passwordController.text.contains(RegExp(r'[0-9]'))) {
          _passwordChecker.hasDigits = true;
        }
        if (_passwordChecker.hasSpecialCharacters = _passwordController.text
            .contains(RegExp(r'[!@#$%^&*(),.?":{}|<>]'))) {
          _passwordChecker.hasSpecialCharacters = true;
        }
      });
    });
  }
```